# Get queryset for a ListView on a boolean field

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I can't understand why this code doesn't work. I have a model called CustomUser with a BooleanField field called expert. I want to filter the users to include users where expert = True.

I've tried self.expert, user___expert and customuser__expert in place of "expert" and none of these worked.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from users.models import CustomUser

class BrowseView(ListView):
    model = CustomUser
    template = 'expert_list.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    experts = CustomUser.objects.filter(expert == True)
    return experts
```

models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    position = models.CharField(max_length =50, null=True, default='')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, default='')
    expert = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter by passing a *named* argument in the `.filter(..)` call, for example:

```
class BrowseView(ListView):
    model = CustomUser
    template = 'expert_list.html'
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(expert=True)
```

Comment: When I do this I get 'name expert is not defined' even though it's a field in my model..

Comment: @user6210879: did you use a *single* `=` (so *not* `==`)?

Comment: I did use ==. Thanks! I think that's why it wasn't working.